# array_rand() need to be the same in while loop

Tags: php, arrays

I have a while loop where I use the value of an array:

```
    while (blablabla) {
            $id = $scene[array_rand($scene)];

  ... few mysql querys using $id

     }
```

Each time I use `$id` I get another value (yes this is what I want), but I would need for each time the while is running another `$id`, but inside the while loop the same value inside `$id` on each query. Is there any possibility ?

Comment: So just to be sure I got you right: You want to have random elements each time, as long as the while loop is running (say element 1, 4, 8, 2, ...) but when you call the while again you want the same sequence (1, 4, 8, 2, ...)? Please try to improve the wording, so we know what you mean.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
while (blablabla) {             
  $id = $scene[array_rand($scene)];   
  $new_id = $id; //create new variable and use this one in the rest of the queries
  ... few mysql querys using $new_id       
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not set the array key once before you use call ID?

```
while ()
{
  $key = array_rand($scene);
  $id = $scene[$key];

  //do something
}
```